# Execute a function automatically according to the time with Java EE 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm working on Java EE 7 and I'm looking for it does exist a way to create a method that automatically according to a timer based on the calendar starts and execute a query trough JPA. is it a possible thing?

Comment: Have you looked at the TimerService?  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-basicexamples004.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use TimerService or Quartz Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

As other's mentioned, you should be using the Timer Service. Here's a simple example, using a Singleton EJB to accomplish the task.

```
@Singleton
public class MyJob {

    @Schedule(minute="0", hour="23")
    public String start() {
        return doStart();
    }

}
```

If it's a long-running process, spend a couple of hours reading about the [Batch Processing JSR](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/batch-processing.htm#GKJIQ6). Batch jobs can also be scheduled using the mentioned Timer Service.